# Kimball Cross Reference Table/Bridge Table

Tags: data-warehouse, dimensional-modeling

I'm currently struggling to understand how to apply Kimball methodology to a certain scenario and talk of Outriggers/Cross Reference/Bridge tables are starting to get confusing.

Consider the scenario:

- We sell software licences.
- Our fact is at the level of a single sale.
- We have an Customer dimension.
- We have a licence dimension.
- We have a licence user dimension.

One customer may purchase many licences.
One licence may have many users.

How do I resolve the one-to-many relationships between the sale fact and the licence dimension and also the one-to-many relationship of the licence dimension and the users dimension?

Bridge tables do not seem appropriate and I cannot find any references in the Kimball documentation to XREF tables even though they are discussed on the (now closed) forums.

Multiple licences are sold as one product so we cannot have a 'licence sale' fact.

Comment: This is the traditional order / orderline problem.
Have a look at this article : https://www.kimballgroup.com/2007/10/design-tip-95-patterns-to-avoid-when-modeling-headerline-item-transactions/